# How to formally express predicate statements?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm revising for an upcoming maths assessment for a theory of algorithms module, but I'm not entirely sure if my solutions to the below questions are correct.

My main confusion with the questions is using this `S(x,y)` statement.

Can anyone review my below answers and correct any errors if present?

[image: predicates]

These are my solutions to the above questions:

(i) ¬∃ x ∈ C [F(x) ^ P(x)]

(ii)∃ x ∈ C [ P(x)[S(x,y)]]

(iii)∀ F(x) ∈ C [ P(x)[S(x,y)]]

(iv)∀ F(x) ∈ C [ P(x)¬[S(x,y)]]

Comment: Here are some hints. In (ii), you also need a quantifier for $y.$ I think (ii) should be $\exists x \in C \exists y \in C: P(x)\wedge F(y)\wedge S(x,y).$ In (iii), you also need a quantifier for $y.$ And maybe you can get some extra credits by pointing out that the formulation "x is a slower than y" in the definition for S(x,y) is bad English (the "a" is superfluous). :-)

Answer (score 1):

(i) $¬∃ x ∈ C \;[F(x) \wedge P(x)]$

$\color{green}{\checkmark}$ "No car is both Ferrari and Porsche."

---

(ii) $∃ x ∈ C [ P(x)[S(x,y)]]$

$\color{red}{\times}$ "some car is a Porsche 'times?' slower than free y"

You need to use a conjunction between the predicates rather than ...multiplying?..., and you must quantify the free variable (and restrict it to Ferrari). Thus:

$$\exists x \in C\; \exists y\in C \; [P(x)\wedge F(y)\wedge S(x,y)]$$

---

(iii) $∀ F(x) ∈ C [ P(x)[S(x,y)]]$

$\color{red}{\times}$ This doesn't even parse. "for all ($x$ is a Ferrari) in cars then $x$ is a Porsche 'times?' $x$ is slower than $y$" ?

---

(iv) $∀ F(x) ∈ C\; [ P(x)¬[S(x,y)]]$

$\color{red}{\times}$ "for all ($x$ is a Ferrari) in cars then $x$ is a Porsche $x$ 'times?' $x$ is not slower than $y$"

A predicate does not belong in the quantification clause, you need to quantify both entities, $x$ and $y$, and to use logical connectives rather than ...multiplying?... the predicates.

---

Remember too that the connective used for a restricted existential is conjunction ($\exists z\; [R(z)\wedge Q(z) ]$) while the connective used for a restricted universal is implication ($\forall z\; [R(z) \to Q(z)]$)

Comment: thanks for the feedback, could you detail the correct solutions for the answers I have incorrect?